# Query projection with MongoDB 10gen driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Recently i was playing with mongodb official driver.
The problem that i've encountered was how to make query projection.
Example if i have a persisted object

```
class A{
  id
  PropA
  PropB
  List<LargeObjects>
}
```

How can i only retrieve id, PropA and PropB instead of retrieving the whole object ?
How can be done with the mongodb official c# driver ?

Comment: Q.P is available through MongoCollection<>.Find().SetFields(include/exclude);

Comment: setfields is in my opinion not a projection. It just makes the value in the document null, so you still have a "complete document, just with some  null values.

Answer (score 13):

Query projection is available through:

```
MongoCollection<>.Find().SetFields(include/exclude);
```

Answer (score 5):

As of v1.8 of the official 10gen MongoDB C# driver, (and as Zambonilli eluded to in a previous answer) the Select linq operator will always be performed on the client side, not on the db server.

Documentation (also provided by Sunil Raj in a previous answer):  http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/

Almost half way down the page, under the "Select" linq query operator, is a large red box that reads:

**Warning: Select does not result in fewer fields being returned from the server. The entire document is pulled back and passed to the native Select method. Therefore, the projection is performed client side.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below linq query for this:

```
//NB: Not tested
    MongoCollection<BsonDocument> Acollection = _db.database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("A");
    var resultlist = (from k in Acollection.AsQueryable<A>()
                                               select k.id,k.PropA,k.PropB);
```

> More information on the linq queries can be found here:
>   http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+LINQ+Tutorial#CSharpDriverLINQTutorial-SupportedLINQqueryoperators

Comment: There was no LINQ implementation back then :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at FluentMongo:

https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo/wiki/Linq

It is available on Nuget aswell, search for "fluentmongo"

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindAs<>` () with a type that includes only the fields you want.  See [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-FindandFindAsmethods).

Add the `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` or the `[BsonExtraElements]` attribute on that class. See [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Supportingextraelements).

Comment: Basically it turned out that SetField calling read from a collection is enough to make the q.p

Answer (score 0):

Using the Mongo profiler I was able to determine that sometimes the Linq results are projected on the client.  Therefore it depends on what your client needs are.  If you want to return a resulting document with partial data from the Mongo server then you'll want to use Marjan or Ian's answers.  Otherwise, if you want to read the record and project it to a different data type then use Linq.